# Heroku Memory quota vastly exceeded in Django Project using SKLearn

Tags: django, heroku, scikit-learn, celery, django-storage

I have deployed a Django application on Heroku with the goal of allowing trusted, known, internal users upload a CSV file, click "Run", and behind the scenes, the Django app:

1. loads a saved sklearn pipeline `.pkl` model (120 MB size, let's say)
2. reads the user's CSV data using Pandas
3. calls `predict` on the model using CSV data as input
4. outputs file to S3 using Django Storages

This works for small CSV files, but causes `Memory quota vastly exceeded` if user uploads a large CSV file... and it makes sense that larger CSV files are going to increase memory consumption.

I'm not sure where to adjust. **I'm wondering if someone out has experienced a similar scenario when deploying sklearn models and how they "solved" it?**

Ideas I have are:

1. Identify memory leaks? No idea really even where to start on this one. Django `DEBUG` is set to `False`.
2. Change my celery task to process the inputted file in chunks instead?
3. Make a smaller SKLearn pipeline file somehow with joblib (I use compress=1 already)?
4. Increase Heroku dynos? workers?

My django models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class MLModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="models/")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Upload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mlmodel = models.ForeignKey(MLModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My celery task looks like this:

```
@shared_task
def piparoo(id):
    instance = Upload.objects.get(id=id)
    model = joblib.load(instance.mlmodel.file.storage.open(instance.mlmodel.file.name))
    data = pd.read_csv(instance.file)
    data['Predicted'] = model.predict(data)

    buffer = StringIO()
    data.to_csv(buffer, index=False)
    content = buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8')
    default_storage.save('output/results_{}.csv'.format(id), ContentFile(content))
```

Heroku logs:

```
2018-04-12T06:12:53.592922+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2018-04-12 06:12:53,592: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: predictions.tasks.piparoo[f1ca09e1-6bba-4115-8989-04bb32d4f08e]
2018-04-12T06:12:53.737378+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/predict/" host=tdmpredict.herokuapp.com request_id=ffad9785-5cb6-4e3c-a87c-94cbca47d109 fwd="24.16.35.31" dyno=web.1 connect=0
ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=6347 protocol=https
2018-04-12T06:13:08.054486+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2018-04-12T06:13:08.054399+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=572M(111.9%)
2018-04-12T06:13:28.026973+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2018-04-12T06:13:28.026765+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=1075M(210.1%)
2018-04-12T06:13:28.026973+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-04-12T06:13:28.187650+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-04-12T06:13:28.306221+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution that resolved my problem (in a common-sense way).

Instead of reading the user's CSV file into memory at once, process it in chunks using Pandas `chunksize` parameter then concatenate the list of dataframes into one at the end. I also delete the model (120 MB) in an attempt to free up that memory for future processes.

My celery task now looks like this:

```
@shared_task
def piparoo(id):
    instance = Upload.objects.get(id=id)
    model = joblib.load(instance.mlmodel.file.storage.open(instance.mlmodel.file.name))

    final = []
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(instance.file, chunksize=5000):
        chunk['Predicted'] = model.predict(chunk)
        final.append(chunk)

    del model
    final = pd.concat(final)

    buffer = StringIO()
    final.to_csv(buffer, index=False)
    content = buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8')
    default_storage.save('output/results_{}.csv'.format(id), ContentFile(content))
```